# Problem that univerwal link didn't worked resolved after device reboot. But Why this works?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm implementing universal link in a project.
I had a problem that universal link didn't open my app.
But after the device which my app run rebooted, it works.
I wonder why device reboot solved this problem.

Comment: Because caching?

Comment: um.. what caching? I want to know how caching machanism is working.